# how to resize a div and its content (images and text) to width of screen while maintaining aspect ratio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, I want to have a div that contains multiple images and text that are layered. When i resize the browser either with height or width, I want the the div, and everything it contains to also resize while maintaining aspect ratio.
Precisely like this example: https://cdpn.io/chriscoyier/debug/VvRoWy but without the drag and drop. it doesnt bother me to use javascript, css, or jquery, just a solid fluid solution.
any ideas?
thanks.

Comment: Hi @Jill John, Stack Overflow works better when your question is specific on one point. Please show us what you've worked, and what is not working on your solution.

Comment: the problem is i have tried so many different ways that i dont know. so i thought i would ask a question with no code to see if people have any solutions I have not tried yet

Comment: Have you tried flex-box?

Comment: For the text you could use a lib like fittext http://fittextjs.com/